# Why is freeing invalid pointers left undefined in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, undefined-behavior, delete-operator

Consider following program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int b=3;
    int* a=&b;
    std::cout<<*a<<'\n';
    delete a;  // oops disaster at runtime undefined behavior
}
```

Ok, behavior of program is undefined according to C++ standard. But my question is why it is left undefined? Why implementations of C++ don't give any compiler errors or any warnings? Is it really hard to determine validity of pointer (means to check whether pointer is returned by new at compile time?) Is there any overhead involved to determine validity of pointer statically (i.e. compile time)?

Comment: That sounds pretty much like asking _"Why does a a unicorn fart not guarantee the order of colors in the resulting rainbow?"_ Not constructive, but I couldn't resist.

Comment: What if the pointer is returned by a function which is defined in another file or brlongs to an external library? The compiler cannot always know how the pointer got its value.

Comment: What behavior would you like to have defined?   You want a defined, guaranteed crash?  What useful purpose does that serve?

Comment: @abelenky: it would be better if defined, guaranteed crash happens every time. Isn't it?

Comment: Some compilers do warn...

Comment: The standard is about defining how ***correct programs run properly*** , not about *easy debugging for bad programs*.   The behavior you're asking for would make development and debugging easier, but would make **correct** programs slower, bigger, or more complex.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Which compiler warn apart from clang?

Comment: Some cases are easy to warn about, and some compilers do so. I'd *almost* go so far as to guess that the general case can't be solved statically.

Comment: gcc warns if you replace `delete` with `free` or provide an inline version of `delete`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: what is inline version of delete? I don't about it. Please explain it

Comment: `inline void operator delete(void*p)noexcept{free(p);}` Technically illegal for no good reason.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is impossible to determine what a pointer points to at compile time, here is an example to illustrate this:

```
volatile bool newAlloc;

int main()
{
   int b=3;
   int* a;
   if(newAlloc)
   {
       a = new int;
   } else {
       a = &b;
   }
   std::cout<<*a<<'\n';
   delete a;  // impossible to know what a will be
}
```

Comment: the branching condition can be evaluated at compile time if you write your code shown in answer in user defined function & make it as an inline. Smart Compiler can perform context specific optimization for inline function when  its body gets substituted at caller function side. So, compiler can focus now on branch prediction. If you say that inline is only a request then you can force compiler for inlining by using __attribute__((always_inline)) in gcc compiler & VC++ compiler also has an option to force inlining.

Comment: @PravasiMeet that's true, in trivial cases it is possible to make assumptions like this (and some static analyzers will point it out). But the small number and nature of cases where it is possible doesn't make it a useful or reliable diagnostic.

Answer (score 9):

Determining if a pointer is valid at compile time is impossible to do in the general case. For example if you have a function as part of a library that takes a pointer as an argument, the compiler cannot determine that it will *always* have a valid pointer passed to it.

The standard leaves deletion of invalid pointers as undefined behavior as otherwise a check would have to be made at runtime every time a pointer is deleted, or indeed dereferenced, this would incur a performance penalty that the language designers didn't want.

Answer (score 7):

> Why implementations of C++ don't give any compiler errors or any warnings?

Clang Static Analyzer does it.

For your piece of code you can get:

```
$ scan-build clang++ main.cpp
scan-build: Using '/usr/bin/clang' for static analysis
main.cpp:7:5: warning: Argument to 'delete' is the address of the local variable 'b', which is not memory allocated by 'new'
    delete a;  // oops disaster at runtime undefined behavior
    ^~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
scan-build: 1 bug found.
```

As mentioned, it's not always possible to determine whether a pointer is valid or not at compile time, but Static Analyzer can definitely help in you your case.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the implementation detail answer:

The `new`/`delete` implementation has to have some way to keep track of some data about all blocks allocated via `new`, especially about their size. Usually, this is done by storing this data in the bytes *before* the start of the allocated block. That way, the implementation of `delete` can very quickly determine how to handle the block. Of course, if you pass in an invalid address, the `delete` implementation will only find bogus data there, possibly crashing your application or silently corrupting data. But that's ok since passing in an invalid address is undefined behavior.

Now, what would be the consequences of making it legal to pass invalid pointers?
The `new`/`delete` implementation would not be able to just look up this information from the pointer that's passed in, because that might be bogus information. The only way to retrieve the necessary information would be to *look up the given pointer in a table of currently valid pointers*. Such a lookup is quite expensive, even if fast lookup algorithms are used; *a lot* slower than just dereferencing the given pointer, anyway.

So it's all about a speed/safety trade-off once again, and C++ opted for speed in this instance.

Comment: Consider also that if pointers are 32 bits, and a program creates more than 4.2 billion objects in its lifetime, some invalid pointers are going to be indistinguishable from valid ones.  It would be possible for a machine with 32-bit addressing to provide almost total safety using 96-bit pointers (each containing a 32-bit handle, a 32-bit allocation count for that handle, and a 32-bit offset), or for a machine with 64-bit addressing but a 4 gig maximum object size to use a similar 128-bit pointer format, but it would have a significant speed penalty (probably a factor of 2-5x or so).